# How can Edit records in a php table by clicking an "Edit" button?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm new to PHP and still learning the language. I created a php page that can show all records in my database on a table (called view_users.php). I also created two buttons "Edit" and "Delete".

I want to be able to edit records on a particular row when I click the "Edit" button attached to it. Is there a way I can do this on the same page (view_users.php).

Below is my source code for view_users.php

```
   <html>
   <head lang="en">
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap.css"> <!--css file link in bootstrap folder-->
   <title>View Users</title>
    </head>
    <style>
.login-panel {
    margin-top: 150px;
}
.table {
    margin-top: 50px;

    }

    </style>

     <body>

       <div class="table-scrol">
       <h1 align="center">All the Users</h1>

          <div class="table-responsive"><!--this is used for responsive display in mobile and other devices-->


         <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped" style="table-layout: fixed">
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <th>User Id</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>User E-mail</th>
        <th>User Pass</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php
    include("database/db_conection.php");
    $view_users_query="select * from users";//select query for viewing users.
     $run=mysqli_query($dbcon,$view_users_query);//here run the sql query.

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run))//while look to fetch the result and store in a array $row.
    {
        $user_id=$row[0];
        $user_name=$row[1];
        $user_email=$row[2];
        $user_pass=$row[3];



    ?>

      <tr>
     <!--here showing results in the table -->
        <td><?php echo $user_id;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user_name;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user_email;  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user_pass;  ?></td>
        <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
        <a href="delete.php?del=<?php echo $user_id ?>"  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a></td>
    </tr>

       <?php } ?>

      </table>
       </div>
      </div>


     </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML page you can add the following code in the action column

Basically your sending the respective **id** by GET parameter.

```
<td>
    <a href="editpage.php?id="<?php echo $userid; ?>>Edit</a>
</td>
```

In your PHP code you can access the **id** as follows :

```
<?php

if(!empty($_GET['id'])){ //Make sure that id parameter is set in your url
    $userid = $filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT); //Now use the 
    //$userid = $_GET['id']; //The above line is safer then this line

    //Now do what ever you want with the id
}
```

Comment: sir can we edit data and pass the respective `id` with `<button>` click?

Comment: @KUMAR yes you can. I have showed the same in HTML. I think your referring to ANCHOR tag. Right? If you meant BUTTON then you cannot. You have to use FORM

Comment: with <button> Tag including <form> Tag we can edit update data or not?

Comment: @KUMAR yes you can make sure you have <button type="submit">

Answer (score 0):

make your edit button:

```
<button type="button" name="<?php echo'edit[$i]'; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
```

$i is the current id of the row in mysql of the record in the while loop.

then at the top of your view_users.php page add something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['edit']))
{
    $row = $_POST['edit']
    ....have form to edit this row
    ....update row $i in database
    ....submit button
}
```